# How to get parent's value from ForeignKey (in django-REST)?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have Banks model class and Branches model class as below :

```
class Banks(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=49, blank=True, null=True)
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'banks'


class Branches(models.Model):
    ifsc = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=11)
    bank = models.ForeignKey(Banks, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    branch = models.CharField(max_length=74, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=195, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=26, blank=True, null=True)
```

My query is as follows :

```
branch = Branches.objects.get(ifsc=IFSC) # where IFSC is passed in URL
```

My serializers look like below :

```
class BranchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Branches
        fields = '__all__'

class BankSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Banks
        fields = '__all__'
```

When i run the mentioned query, i get the following output:(example)

```
{
    "ifsc": "UTIB0000007",
    "branch": "NEW DELHI",
    "address": "STATESMAN HOUSE,  148, BARAKHAMBA ROAD",
    "city": "DELHI",
    "district": "NEW DELHI",
    "state": "DELHI",
    "bank": 13
}
```

Here 13 (in this example) is ForeignKey, But i want the value of that bank(i.e parent) instead of the key.

The desired output should look like :

```
{
    "ifsc": "UTIB0000007",
    "branch": "NEW DELHI",
    "address": "STATESMAN HOUSE,  148, BARAKHAMBA ROAD",
    "city": "DELHI",
    "district": "NEW DELHI",
    "state": "DELHI",
    "bank": "BANK NAME"
}
```

Please help me with this, i am new to django-REST and detailed explanation will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a field in the serializer

```
class BranchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bank = serializers.CharField(source='bank.name')

    class Meta:

        model = Branches
        fields = '__all__'
```

Output is:

```
{
    "ifsc": "UTIB0000007",
    "branch": "NEW DELHI",
    "address": "STATESMAN HOUSE,  148, BARAKHAMBA ROAD",
    "city": "DELHI",
    "district": "NEW DELHI",
    "state": "DELHI",
    "bank": "BANK NAME"
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!, i am very grateful for this solution, can you please recommend me some resources for learning serializers in detail like this?

Comment: Welcome @hack3r_0m 
I suggest you follow the rest framework official document.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/